# quantum espresso getting mpirun error

Tags: 20.04, software-sources, quantum

i am doing phonon calculation in quantum espresso. while doing it i am getting an error like..

```
**********-ideapad:gr$ mpirun ph.x <sample.ph.in> sample.ph.out

Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
STOP 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[3530,1],1]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

can anyone help me with this.

thank you,
krk.

Comment: IEEE_DENORMAL is [(mostly) harmless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309751/4440445) and the fact that QE emits it appears to be a known issue e.g. [Quantum ESPRESSO (at least) prints IEEE_DENORMAL and similar floating-point exceptions](https://github.com/marvel-nccr/quantum-mobile/issues/52). That mpirun aborts when any process terminates with non-zero status looks like it may be configurable at least in the case of the OpenMPI implementation (search the man page for MCA parameter "orte_abort_on_non_zero_status")

Comment: yes i check it and my pc has 4 cores and after that i run the command "mpirun -np 2 ph.x -nk 1 <sample.ph.in> sample.ph.out" but this also gave me the sam error.

Comment: Rather, my suggestion was to try something like `mpirun -mca orte_abort_on_non_zero_status 0 ph.x <sample.ph.in> sample.ph.out`